# Not able to form a Cassandra cluster of two nodes in Windows?

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, datastax

I am trying to setup two nodes of Cassandra cluster on my windows machine. Basically, I have two windows machine. In both of my machine, I have installed Cassandra 1.2.11 from Datastax. Now I was following this [tutorial](http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/how-to-setup-and-monitor-a-multi-node-cassandra-cluster-on-windows) to setup two node Cassandra Cluster.

After installing Cassandra into those two machines, I stopped the services for the Cassandra server, DataStax OpsCenter, and the DataStax OpsCenter agent in those two machines..

And then I started making changes in the yaml file -

My First Node details are -

```
initial_token: 0
seeds: "10.0.0.4"  
listen_address: 10.0.0.4   #IP of Machine - A (Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection)
rpc_address: 10.0.0.4
```

My Second Node details are -

```
initial_token: 0
seeds: "10.0.0.4"    
listen_address: 10.0.0.7   #IP of Machine - B (Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection)
rpc_address: 10.0.0.7
```

Both of my serves gets started up properly after I start the services for server. But they are not forming a cluster of two nodes somehow? Is there anything I am missing here?

Machine-A Nodetool Information-

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
==========
Replicas: 1

Address   Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token


10.0.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  212.1 KB        100.00%             5264744098649860606
```

Machine-B Nodetool Information-

```
Starting NodeTool

Datacenter: datacenter1
==========
Replicas: 1

Address   Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token


10.0.0.7  rack1       Up     Normal  68.46 KB        100.00%             407804996740764696
```

Both of my laptops are running Windows 7 64 bit and on the same wi-fi network, sitting next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak firewall. Cassandra installer does not open firewall for itself. You have to go and create one more Inbound TCP rule. These are the [default ports](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/firewall_ref) of DataStax Community edition of Cassandra database: `7000, 7001, 9160, 7199, 9042, 8888, 50031, 61620, 8012, 9290, 50030, 50060, 61621, 22, 8983`, but I ended up with `10-65535` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Two nodes with the same intial_token cannot be in the same cluster (even if they are in different data centers). Initial tokens must be unique for each node and it is best to set them so that they span the full range of the partitioner you using.

Comment: I see.. I have also tried keeping initial_token as empty, the way it was earlier as default.. And still it doesnt works for me..

Comment: Your nodetool output looks like you had it blank for that run (tokens look auto-assigned).

Try nodetool -h 10.0.0.7 ring from the 10.0.0.4 node, if that works then that means jmx is up and accessible from 10.0.0.4. 

If that is the case you'll need to look in the cassandra logs to see the details of the gossip interactions.

Comment: After trying your above suggestion.. Now I am getting - Failed to connect to `10.0.0.7` Connection Timed Out..